# Combine lists into tuple with specific pairing

Tags: python, list, tuples

If I have

```
colours = [ "red", "green", "yellow"]
animals = [ "mouse", "tiger", "elephant" ]
coloured_animals = [ (x,y) for x in colours for y in things ]
```

What do I need to add so that the list comprehension returns
("red","mouse"), ("green","tiger"),("yellow","elephant") instead of all pairings?

Answer (score 3):

python has the builtin function `zip` for this

```
>>> colours = [ "red", "green", "yellow"]
>>> animals = [ "mouse", "tiger", "elephant" ]
>>> zip(colours, animals)
[('red', 'mouse'), ('green', 'tiger'), ('yellow', 'elephant')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in function `zip`, but if you wanted to fix your list comprehension, here's how you would do it, provided that `len(colours) <= len(animals)`:

```
>>> coloured_animals = [(colours[x], animals[x]) for x in range(len(colours))]
>>> coloured_animals
[('red', 'mouse'), ('green', 'tiger'), ('yellow', 'elephant')]
>>>
```